# BigQuery JDBC driver won't return more than 100,000 rows

Tags: pentaho, google-bigquery

I am using the starschema JDBC driver for Google BigQuery in Pentaho PDI:

http://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/

My query through the BigQuery Web Console returns 129,993 rows, but when I execute the same query through the JDBC driver it only returns 100,000 rows.  Is there some kind of option or limit that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StarSchema code looks like it is only returning the first page of results.

The code here [here](https://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/source/browse/src/main/java/net/starschema/clouddb/jdbc/BQSupportFuncts.java#330) should be updated to get the rest of the results. It should look something like:

```
public static GetQueryResultsResponse getQueryResults(Bigquery bigquery,
        String projectId, Job completedJob) throws IOException {        
    GetQueryResultsResponse queryResult = bigquery.jobs()
            .getQueryResults(projectId,
                    completedJob.getJobReference().getJobId()).execute();
    while(queryResult.getTotalRows() > queryResult.getRows().size()) {
        queryResult.getRows().addAll(
            bigquery.jobs()
                .getQueryResults(projectId,
                        completedJob.getJobReference().getJobId())
                .setStartIndex(queryResult.getRows().size())
                .execute()
                .getRows());            
    }
    return queryResult;
}
```

Comment: I have downloaded the source and I am attempting to re-compile it with these changes.  Not having much luck.

Answer (score 1):

Modified the code based on Jordan's answer, the solution looks like this:

```
    public static GetQueryResultsResponse getQueryResults(Bigquery bigquery,
        String projectId, Job completedJob) throws IOException {
    GetQueryResultsResponse queryResult = bigquery.jobs()
            .getQueryResults(projectId,
                    completedJob.getJobReference().getJobId()).execute();
    long totalRows = queryResult.getTotalRows().longValue();
    if(totalRows == 0){ 
//if we don't have results we'll get a nullPointerException on the queryResult.getRows().size()
        return queryResult;
    }
    while( totalRows  > (long)queryResult.getRows().size() ) {
        queryResult.getRows().addAll(
            bigquery.jobs()
                .getQueryResults(projectId,
                        completedJob.getJobReference().getJobId())
                .setStartIndex(BigInteger.valueOf((long)queryResult.getRows().size()) )
                .execute()
                .getRows());           
    }
    return queryResult;
}
```

This should solve the problem.
Also uploaded the new version to google code, named [bqjdbc-1.3.1.jar](http://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/downloads/detail?name=bqjdbc-1.3.1.jar)